# Is it permitted to deviate from yellow lines, during taxi?

Tags: taxiing, airport-markings

During taxi procedures, the pilot should follow the yellow lines, to avoid a collision with any obstacle or even with another aircraft. Is the any situation, which the pilot can deviate from the yellow line at their own discretion?

Comment: Not just permitted, but [sometimes explicitly encouraged for large aircraft](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/41015/what-is-judgemental-oversteering-in-taxi-procedures).

Comment: It is, however, generally a good idea to [go down the middle of the runway.](http://avherald.com/h?article=42cb3476)

Comment: Some taildraggers do S-turns down the taxiway to be able to see in front of them.

Answer (score 8):

There's no rule that you have to follow the lines, they're there purely as a guide, a reference for pilots to know where the center of the taxi lane is. Following it is at a pilot's discretion, to be deviated from at any point. Generally you follow the line because it's easy and it should keep you out of trouble, common reasons for deviating are:

- Obstructions: vehicles, people, debris
- Clearance: airplanes with large wingspans may need to hug one side of a taxiway to get around parked airplanes or buildings. In a small airfield you'll often have to get around a parked airplane or two